# Check if someone is logged in using Silex PHP Framework

Tags: php, symfony, silex

When I log in and show no actions for two hours I will automatically log out. But when I refresh the page I get the error that Silex can't find the attribute displayName on a null attribute. Because in my layout view I have: `{{ app.user.displayName }}`.

Now I would like to check in my $app->before if someone is logged in, and if not redirect to root. This is what I have now:

```
    $app->before(function (Request $request) use($app) {
    if ($request->getMethod() === "OPTIONS") {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type");
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","handshake");
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->send();
    }

    $token = $app['security']->getToken();
    if (null === $token) {
        die;
    }
});
```

The problem is that it's never null, also when I'm not logged in. I've made a dump from the $token variable from when I'm not logged in and I get this:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken)#525 (5) { 
  ["key":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken":private]          => string(12) "secured_area" 
  ["user":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]          => string(5) "anon."
  ["roles":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]         => array(0) { } 
  ["authenticated":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private] => bool(true) 
  ["attributes":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]    => array(0) { }
}
```

My login route is defined like this:

```
$controllers->get('/', 'user.controller:loginAction')
            ->bind('user.login');
```

How can I redirect to that route?

Comment: Did you define some `firewalls` somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should better check is the user doesn't have [the anonymous role](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#checking-user-roles).

```
if ($app['security']->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')) {
    // do action while the user isn't logged in
}
```

Comment: and how can I redirect to the root, because the login route has '/' path. Because when I do know: return $app->redirect('/'); I get 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'

Comment: You should redirect him to the login page instead. The user is anonymously authenticated. Until he will be authenticated as a real user, it will remain anonymously authenticated.

Comment: Updated my begin post, could you take a look?

Comment: Then you should check if you aren't in the login page in your $app->before

Comment: And what if I'm not? How can I redirect to '/' ? When I do redirect('/') I get an error to many redirects ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(null == $app['security']->getToken()->getUser()){
    die;
}
```

Really you shouldnt use die though. You should redirect or throw some exception. But for debugging die is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not a symphony user, but i imagine the following will work:

```
if ($token->user=='anon') {
        die;
    }
```